# Lost previous combobox item style after applying style for cursor on hover

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I want all clickable elements in the app to have hand cursor on hover. My problem is in comboboxes: all of them apply default (or what?) style when I set my custom style below (but hand cursor works!):

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>

<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource OptionTextBlockStyle}" />
            <ComboBox x:Name="SortTypesComboBox" FontSize="14px" DisplayMemberPath="Description" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}">
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
```

The first image is what I want but with hand cursor on clickable items, the second one is what I actually have applying my comboboxitemstyle.

[image: demanded style but without hand cursor]

[image: wrong combobox style but with right cursor]

I don't know why I lost my previous style using this line ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}. How can I save it and make right cursor on hover at the same time?

---UPG----
I've just added BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBoxItem}}" line and this didn't help me much. Now I have my items with wrong style and green lightning:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The way that you define your style overrides the default style for `ComboBox`. Instead, you should base your style on the default style using the [`BasedOn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.style.basedon?view=netcore-3.1#examples) property.

```
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxItemStyle"
       TargetType="ComboBoxItem"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBoxItem}}">
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The reason for referencing the default style with `{x:Type ComboBoxItem}` is that it is an [implicit style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/fundamentals/styles-templates-create-apply-style?view=netdesktop-5.0#apply-a-style-implicitly), which gets applied automatically to each control of that type in scope unless a different style is assigned explicitly and the `x:Key` of an implicit style is their `TargetType`.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I rewrite style with "BasedOn..." and my combobox's items are with wrong style and green lightning on them. Pls look at my upgraded question

Comment: @АлександраЮреня To clarify, you **do not have** a style that looks like your first image, you just created the style above and it happens to look like you want, but does not work anymore? Or do you have created a style that looks  like in the second image?

Comment: i don't have a style that looks like my first image. It looks like I want without any of them (without ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}" it looks fine but no hand cursor I want). If I apply comboboxitemstyle my needed first picture of items will lost. Hope I made it more clear

Comment: @АлександраЮреня Where did you put the style, in which resource dictionary? Try to put the style with `BasedOn` into the `StackPanel .Resources`, does it work then?

Comment: I put the style in UserControl.Resourses where others styles contain. Now I put it to StackPanel .Resources as you said and nothing changes

Comment: @АлександраЮреня The implicit, default style (third picture) has to come from somewhere, either you have defined it yourself or it is from a library. The style in the first picture is different. It has to be defined somewhere and applied, too, otherwise the `ComboBoxItem`s would apply the implicit style from the third picture. Moreover, in the first picture the style does not look right, as there are only two items displayed, while the other picures show the selected item and the list of items to choose from. From the provided code is hard to guess what the problem actually is.

Comment: @АлександраЮреня Did you ever have the style displayed in the first picture or is it just a sample picture? If you didn't, your question is misleading, as it states that you want to have a hand cursor on mouse over, not creating a completely different style. In order to do that, you would need to create a new control template for `ComboBoxItem`.